# My python Prime Number Finder doesn't work

Tags: python, primes

My code is:

```
currentNum = 0
divisible = True
prime = 0
counter = 1
counter2 = 1
counter3 = 0
counter4 = 0
while not counter == 10:
    while not counter2 == counter:
        currentNum = counter / counter2
        while not counter3 == counter:
            if currentNum == counter3:
                counter4 = counter4 + 1
        if counter4 == 1:
            divisible = True
            counter4 = 0
        else:
            divisible = False
            prime = prime + 1
            counter4 = 0
    counter3 = 0
    counter2 = 1
    counter = counter + 1
print(prime)
```

but for some reason it only shows `0.5` whenever I try to use it.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly it's *supposed* to be doing. You say it's a prime number finder, but what algorithm are you trying to implement? What's with all of the counters?

Comment: No idea what you are trying to implement but you should definitely not be getting fractions back, you need  `currentNum = counter // counter2`

Answer (score 0):

Well first 0 and 1 are not prime numbers so we must take care of that. Also 2 is prime so we must also take care of that. Now that the outlier prime numbers are out we can focus on the normal ones.

A prime number can only be divided by 1 and itself. So we must make a list to and make sure our input can't be divided by any number in that list. Also even numbers are out of the playing field since they can be divided by 2.

First I make a function to check the input against every number up to the number to see if it can be divided by other numbers. Then I check if the number is even (num%2 is a good way to check if something is even) or if the number can be divided by any other number.

See how I put the even check first to save time if the number is even we don't have to check all the numbers in the list we can just return false without iterating through the entire list.

```
def is_prime(num):

    if num < 0 or num in [0,1]:
        return False
    elif num == 2: 
        return True   

    def prime_range_check():
        for number in range(2,num):
            if num%number == 0:
                return False

    if num % 2 == 0 or prime_range_check() == False:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: you actually only need to check up to `num/2`